# Meaning of # in for loop for bash

Tags: bash, for-loop

What does the # mean in a for loop in bash? Unfortunately, I don't get information googling about it.

For example:

```
for n in 2 3 4 # 5 6 7 8 9 10
do
...
done
```

?

Comment: It's a comment character, just like in any other context.

Comment: ...so, the original loop covered `2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`, but `5` and onward are commented out, so only `2`, `3` and `4` run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `#` simple is a 1-line comment, like the `//` in C++ and Java.
This is a comment example:

```
int i = 0; // Declare an integer to 0.
```

And then, in bash

```
# Test script
for n in 2 3 4 # 5 6 7 8 9 10
do
echo $n # But don't do this text to the right of the #
done
```